# differential of a product of two quantities

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So far I've always blindly done a sort of product rule on a differential like this
$$ d(\rho V) = \rho dV + V d\rho$$
I'm now wondering if it is also legitimate to write 
$$ d(\rho V) = \rho dV + V d\rho + d\rho \: dV$$
(This would be handy for an application in physics I'm doing). I realise $d\rho \: dV$ is a small term so it goes to zero anyway in the infinitesimal limit but what I'd like to know is if it is in fact the actual the next lowest order term. Is there an infinite expansion for $d(\rho V)$? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to add to Chappers' answer, $d(\rho V)$ is literally 100% equal to $\rho\,dV + V\,d\rho$: there are no lower-order terms, just as $2x = x + x$ doesn't have any lower-order terms.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really no: $d$ on functions is normally defined as a map having the Leibnitz property
$$ d(ab)= a \, db+ b \, da $$
(as well as linearity).